# @KafkaListener doesn't read previous messages even if they were not acknowledge unless application restarts

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

So basically What I'm seeing is that I'm using @KafkaListener to consume messages and deliberately I don't want to acknowledge them so the consumer ignores them and listens for new messages in the topic. Hence, consumer only starts to from the last committed message if the application is restarted. Therefore, I would want to avoid this situation I would want consumer to consider uncommitted messages without restarting. Below is the configuration and @kafkalistener that I'm using.

ReceiverConfig.java

```
package com.config;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class ReceiverConfig {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String bootstrapServers;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.group}")
    private String group;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.auto-offset-reset}")
    private String offset;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, group);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "CAS-CLIENT-001");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "3000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, offset);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false); //TODO Remove if you want Kafka to automatically acknowledge
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 1);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 30000);
        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        factory.setConcurrency(1);
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE); //TODO Remove if you want Kafka to automatically acknowledge
        return factory;
    }
}
```

and ReceiverService

```
package com.service;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.Acknowledgment;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.Payload;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class ReceiverService {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReceiverService.class);

    @KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.topic}")
    private synchronized void consumeKafkaQueue(@Payload String message, Acknowledgment acknowledgment) {
        LOG.info("Received message from kafka queue: {}", message);
        //TODO Do your code here...
        //acknowledgment.acknowledge();
        //Note if the "acknowledgment" parameter is left out Kafka will be acknowledged as soon as the method finishes.
    }
}
```

Comment: According to this `I would want consumer to consider uncommitted messages without restarting.` No you cannot

Comment: is there a way to tell consumer to repoll after certain time and look for uncommitted messages, or reset the seek() value when using @KafkaListener

Answer (score 0):

what value have?

```
@Value("${spring.kafka.auto-offset-reset}")
    private String offset;
```

[here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs) you can see all consumer configs

> What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current offset does not exist any more on the server (e.g. because that data has been deleted):
>
> earliest: automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset
>
> latest: automatically reset the offset to the latest offset
>
> none: throw exception to the consumer if no previous offset is found for the consumer's group
>
> anything else: throw exception to the consumer.

You should use earliest

Comment: it is earliest, but still it doesn't read the uncommitted message after processing for the first time until the application is restarted

Answer (score 0):

You must implement ConsumerSeekAware, were you register callback

```
@Override
public void registerSeekCallback(ConsumerSeekCallback consumerSeekCallback) {
  this.consumerSeekCallback = consumerSeekCallback;
}
```

after that you can call seek in place not acks

```
if(...){
  acknowledgment.acknowledge();
}else{
  consumerSeekCallback.get().seek(consumerRecord.topic(), consumerRecord.partition(), consumerRecord.offset());
}
```

it's happening, because spring use internal batch message and use this code for check acks:

```
protected void pollAndInvoke() {
  if (!this.autoCommit && !this.isRecordAck) {
    processCommits();
  }
    idleBetweenPollIfNecessary();
  if (this.seeks.size() > 0) {
    processSeeks();
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The consumer wouldn't read the past several messages even if they are uncommitted until the app is restarted or some way the re-balancing is triggered. Please refer the below excerpt from Kafka Definitive Guide.

*After the rebalancing, all consumers will start consuming from the last offset committed.*

you can force the ReBalancing by connecting few consumers and remove one. Once the default 10 seconds limit is passed, the Re-Balancing would be triggered and you could see the remaining consumers would read those messages.

Moreover there is no relation of `auto.offset.reset` property here.

You can play creating the Kafka cluster by simply following the Readme here.

### https://github.com/skshukla/infra